# Confused about how to heat water with water heater alone

Tags: hot-water

I have a water heater, a boiler and an oil burner.  I'm not sure if you're allowed to state names of products on stackexchange so I apologize in advance if by naming names I break the rules.  The water heater is a Rheem 120 gallon electric water heater.  The boiler is a CSFH IV series 4 water oil fired cast iron boiler.  And the oil burner is an AF/AFG Beckett burner.

I have to turn off the oil burner manually once a day because I cannot get the radiators to cease emitting heat but that is another problem.  What I want to know now is how do I turn off the oil burner but not lose the ability to heat water at the same time.

On my Rheem water heater it says "Summer - Turn on breaker, close two back valves, open valve to water heater.  Winter - Turn off breaker, open two back valves, close valve to water heater."  I didn't buy the water heater so I'm not familiar with what that means.

I've set things to the Summer settings but I still cannot get the water to heat if I turn the oil burner off. Am I doing something wrong or is the equipment broken?

If the pictures are too dark. Let me know.  I'm at work right now and can't take better pics until tomorrow

[image: water heateer]

[image: water heater 2]
[image: oil burner]

Comment: It sounds like you have a setup where in the winter you use the oil burner/boiler to produce hot water for bathing/washing dishes/etc. and to heat via the radiators and in the winter you use the electric water heater. That is unusual but should work. So the next step is to see if the water heater is actually getting any power when you turn the breaker on. May need a multimeter to check it out.

Comment: Yes, you can name products on SE -- calling a Rheem a Rheem won't offend Rheem's senses any

Comment: Can you post photos of the equipment in question please?

Comment: I have a similar setup.  Can use the water heater power to heat water, or an outside wood furnace to heat water.  It sounds like something is not right/working with the water heater itself.  Possibilities are electrodes not working, water heater thermostat off or too low, or no power from the breaker to heater.